# On quantizing color images in Matlab

Tags: matlab

So I've been juggling various methods of quantizing an image, I've ran into a snag when it comes to color images. My first attempt was to quantize the color image itself, and the other attempt was to seperate the bands and quantize themselves:

first method

```
CL1R = uint8(floor(OredChannel / 128) * 128); % 256 / 2 = 128
CL1G = uint8(floor(OgreenChannel / 128) * 128); % 256 / 2 = 128
CL1B = uint8(floor(OblueChannel / 128) * 128); % 256 / 2 = 128
CL1A = cat(3,CL1R,CL1G,CL1B);
```

second:

```
CL1 = uint8(floor(C1 / 128) * 128); % 256 / 2 = 128
```

but they seem to yield a different image than what I am trying to replicate with the imquantize method, and I don't want to use it. For turning an original G-level image into a K level image, am  I suppose to convert it through this method?

```
(int)((double)I*K/G)*G/K
```

I was trying to look at what to use for first turning the color image into a K level image but its a bit unclear.

Comment: Indeed, here you need vector quantization. If you treat each element of the RGB vector independently, you end up with N*N*N different colors, rather than N.

Comment: Ah hey Cris. I wanted to put this on the other topic but I felt this was a bit more seperate. Anyways while I understand I I'm a bit unclear on what G is. Was gonna use 2 as an example for K.